# c-string being saved to the end of another c-string

Tags: c++, arrays, structure, getline, c-strings

I am making a program to store a library's book collection. One of the options is to add a new book to an array of structures.

**Here is the code**

```
do
{
    repeat = 0;

    cout << "Enter the book's title: ";
    cin.getline(tempTitle, (TITLE_SIZE) * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < bookNumber; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(tempTitle, bookArray[i].title) == 0)
        {
            cout << "That title has already been entered, please enter a new book\n";
            repeat = 1;
        }
    }

    if (strlen(tempTitle) < 1 || strlen(tempTitle) > TITLE_SIZE)
    {
        cout << "The Book's title must be between 1 and 50 characters long\n";
        repeat = 1;
    }

} while (repeat == 1);

strncpy(bookArray[bookNumber].title, tempTitle, TITLE_SIZE);
file << bookArray[bookNumber].title << "\n";


do
{
    repeat = 0;

    cout << "Enter the book's ISBN number: ";
    cin.getline(tempIsbn, (ISBN_SIZE) * 2);

    if (strlen(tempIsbn) != ISBN_SIZE)
    {
        cout << "The Book's title must be 13 digits long\n";
        repeat = 1;
    }

} while (repeat == 1);

strncpy(bookArray[bookNumber].isbn, tempIsbn, ISBN_SIZE);
```

**Here is my input**

```
Enter the book's title: new book title
Enter the book's ISBN number: 0000000000000
Enter the book's author: Person
Is the book currently in stock (y/n)? y
```

**Here is what it is saved as**

```
Title : new book title
ISBN #: 0000000000000Person
Author: Person
Status: Available
```

Why is it saving the author c-string to the end of the isbn c-string?

Answer (score 0):

book::ISBN seems to be a 13-element char array. If you pass this array to a C string processing function, the function receives just the start address and not the length, so it scans the memory for a byte with the numeric value 0 (not ASCII '0'), and considers that to be the end of the string. The thirteen chars in ISBN are completely filled by the digits, and directly followed by the author, so printing of the ISBN goes on until the terminating 0 byte of the author member.

You can do a limited-length printing like this for example:

```
printf("ISBN: %.13s\n", books[index].ISBN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic of inputing data is invalid. For example if data member `isbn` is defined like

```
char isbn[ISBN_SIZE];
```

where `ISBN_SIZE` is equal to `13`  then this data member can store only `12` digits because the last character of the array will store the terminating zero.

So you should define `ISBN_SIZE` as equal to `14` if you want that data member `isbn`. would store `13` digits.

Also if `isbn` has size `ISBN_SIZE` then it is not clear why you use expression 
`(ISBN_SIZE) * 2` to enter a value.

```
cin.getline(tempIsbn, (ISBN_SIZE) * 2);
```

Thus after enetering a value data member `isbn` does not contain the terminating zero of the string.

The corresponding code snippet could look the following way

```
bool repeat = false; // the initialization only for exposition

do
{
    cout << "Enter the book's ISBN number: ";
    cin.getline( tempIsbn, ISBN_SIZE );

    if ( repeat = ( strlen( tempIsbn ) != ISBN_SIZE - 1 ) )
    {
        cout << "The Book's ISDN number must be " << ISBN_SIZE - 1 << " digits long\n";
    }

} while ( repeat );

strcpy( bookArray[bookNumber].isbn, tempIsbn );
```

The same remarks are valid for entering the title of a book.